# Upgrade SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, upgrade

If I need to upgrade MSSQL 2000 TO MSSQL 2005 which is installed inside the citrix

box. How can I check if it is compatible or not.

Thanks

Comment: Check of what is compatible or not?

Comment: you're not supposed to ask questions that aren't directly related to programming on stackoverflow so you'll probably get voted down :/

Answer (score 2):

To test compatibility you need to setup a test environment which roughly duplicates the expected live environment.

That is to say you need to setup a Citrix server with much the same setup as your live citrix server and install SQL Server 2005 on it as you expect to install it on the live server and then run your applications in the SQL 2005 server environment.

It all depends on what compatibility you are testing.